# Cannon run executable app with su privileges

Tags: android, root, openvpn, su

I want to run openvpn binary from command line in app on my rooted device. It's rooted alright (I checked it a few times already). I'm using

```
 Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

For this, but on the very end I get error:

```
Note: Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted (errno=1)
Attempting fallback to kernel 2.2 TUN/TAP interface
Cannot allocate TUN/TAP dev dynamically
Exiting
```

I tried running it with

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c "+command);
```

I tried

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", command});
```

and I tried using method from http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html - everything failed, not even one time it run (no response or ANR error).

Could you help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow the app in superuser.

Comment: I have busybox installed and app is giving me su privileges. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Comment: try to run another root command and see if that works?  That eror you are getting is because openvpn doesnt have root access.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is because of that. I'll check it in a moment.